# C: Replacing a substring within a string using loops

Tags: c, string, loops, substring

I am struggling with the concept of replacing substrings within strings. This particular exercise does not want you to use built in functions from `<string.h>` or `<strings.h>`.

Given the string made up of two lines below:

```
"Mr. Fay, is this going to be a battle of wits?" 
"If it is," was the indifferent retort, "you have come unarmed!"
```

I have to replace a substring with another string.

This is what I have so far, and I'm having trouble copying the substring to a new array, and replacing the substring with the new string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int dynamic();

int main()
{
    char str[]="\n\"Mr. Fay, is this going to be a battle of wits?\" \n\"If it is,\" was the indifferent retort, \"you have come unarmed!\"";

    int i, j=0, k=0, l=0, n=0;
    unsigned int e = n-2;

    char data[150];
    char newData[150];
    char newStr[150];

    printf("Give me a substring from the string");
    gets(data);

    printf("Give me a substring to replace it with");
    gets(newData);

    dynamic();

    for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != data[j])
        {
            newStr[l] = str[i];
            l++;
        }
        else if ((str[i+e] == data[j+e]) && (j<n))
        {
            newStr[l] = newData[j];
            j++;
            l++;
            e--;
        }
        else if ((str[i+e] == data[j+e]) && (j>=n))
        {
            j++;
            e--;
        }
        else
        {
            newStr[l] = str[i];
            l++;
        }
    }

    printf("original string is-");

    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
        printf("%c",str[k]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("modified string is-");

    for(k=0; k<n; k++)
        printf("%c",newStr[k]);
    printf("\n");
}

int dynamic()
{
    char str[]="\n\"Mr. Fay, is this going to be a battle of wits?\" \n\"If it is,\" was the indifferent retort, \"you have come unarmed!\"";

    int i, n=0;

    for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        n++;
    }
    printf("the number of characters is %d\n",n);

    return (n);
}
```

Comment: You should at least add what it is doing wrong – after all, you tried to run this code, didn't you? If you find a non-matching character, you should reset `dataIndex` back to `0`, and also `strIndex` to the position where you started matching. As it is, you are always ending up at the first `i`. (At a passing glance, you have a similar problem in the replacement routine.)

Comment: Oh my bad, what is happening is that when I try to print the last loop, nothing shows up. So basically, I should return 0; after each loop?

Comment: You didn't reset strIndex, which means the first thing it finds is '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your problem and got output for my code. Here is the code- 
**EDIT- THIS IS THE EDITED MAIN CODE**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int var(char *);  //function declaration. I am telling CPU that I will be using this function in the later stage with one argument of type char *

int main()   //main function
{

    char *str="\n\"Mr. Fay, is this going to be a battle of wits?\" \n\"If it is,\" was the indifferent retort, \"you have come unarmed!\"";
    int i,j=0,k=0,l=0;
    char data[] = "indifferent";
    char newData[] = "nonchalant";
    char newStr[150];
    //here  'n' is returned from the 'var' function and is received in form of r,r1,r2,r3.
    int r=var(str);  //getting the length of str from the function 'var' and storing in 'r'
    int r1=var(data);  //getting the length of data from the function 'var' and storing in 'r1'
    int r2=var(newData);  //getting the length of newData from the function and storing in 'r2'
    unsigned int e=r1-2;  //r1-2 because r1 is the data to be replaced. and string index starts from 0. Here r1 is of length 12. but we dont need to check last
    //character because it is null character and the index starts from 0. not from 1. so, it is 0 to 11 and 11th is '\0'. so "12-"2"=10" characters to be compared.
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {

        if(str[i]!=data[j])
        {
            newStr[l]=str[i];
            l++;
        }
        else if((str[i+e]==data[j+e]) && (j<r2))
        {
            newStr[l]=newData[j];
            j++;
            l++;
            e--;

        }
        else if((str[i+e]==data[j+e]) && (j>=r2))
        {
            j++;
            e--;
        }
        else
        {
            newStr[l]=str[i];
            l++;    
        }

    }
    int r3=var(newStr);  //getting the length of str from the function and storing in 'r'
    printf("original string is-");
    for(k=0;k<r;k++)
    printf("%c",str[k]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("modified string is-");
    for(k=0;k<r3;k++)
    printf("%c",newStr[k]);
    printf("\n");
} // end of main function

 // Below is the new function called 'var' to get the character length
//'var' is the function name and it has one parameter. I am returning integer. so, it is int var.

int var(char *stri)//common function to get length of strings and substrings
{
    int i,n=0;
    for(i=0;stri[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        n++; //n holds the length of a string.
    }
   // printf("the number of characters is %d\n",n);
    return (n); //returning this 'n' wherever the function is called.
}
```

Let me explain few parts of the code-

1. I have used unsigned int e, because I don't want 'e' to go negative.(I will explain more about this later).
2. In the first for loop, I am checking whether my string has reached the end.
3. In first 'IF' condn, I am checking whether the first character of string is NOT-EQUAL to the first character of the word which needs to be replaced. If condition satisfies, print regularly thr original string.
4. ELSE IF, i.e(first character of string is EQUAL to the first character of the word)then check the next few characters to make sure that the word matches. Here, I used 'e' because it will check the condition for str[i+e] and data[i+e]. example- ai notequalto ae. If I had not used 'e'in code,... after checking the first character itself, newdata would have been printed in newstr. I used 'e'=5 because the probabilty of 1st letter and 5th letter being the same in data and the str is less. You can use 'e'=4 also. No rule that you have to use 'e'=5 only.
5. Now, I am decrementing 'e' and checking whether the letters in the string is same or no. I can't increment because, there is a certain limit of size of a string. As, I used unsigned int, 'e' won't go down below 0.
6. ELSE, (this means that only first letter is matching, the 5th letter of str and data are not matching), print the str in newstr.
7. In the last FOR loop, I have used k<114 because, that much characters are there in the string. (You can write a code to find how many characters are there in a string. No need to manually count).
8. And lastly, I have used conditions (j<10) and (j>=10) along with ELSE-IF condition because, in first ELSE-IF, the new data is ofsize 10. So, even if the word to be replaced is more than 10,say 12 for example. I  don't need the extra 2 bits to be stored in new data. So, if the size is more than 10, just bypass that in the next ELSE-IF condition. Note that this 10 is the size of new word. So, it varies if your word is smaller or bigger. And , in second ELSE-IF, I am not incrementing 'l'(l++) because, here, I am not putting anything in newstr. I am just bypassing it. So, I didn't increment.

I tried my best to put the code in words. If you have any doubt, you can ask again. I will be glad to help. And this code is NOT OPTIMAL. The numerical values used varies with the words/strings you use. Ofcourse, I can write a generalized code for that(to fetch the numerical values automatically from the strings). But, I didn't write that code here. This code works for your problem. You can change few variables like 'e' and ELSE-IF part and try to understand how the code works. Play with it.

EDIT-

## include

```
int main()
{
    char str[]="\n\"Mr. Fay, is this going to be a battle of wits?\" \n\"If it is,\" was the indifferent retort, \"you have come unarmed!\"";// I took this as string. The string which u need to calculate the length, You have to pass that as the function parameter.
    int i,n=0;
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        n++;
    }
    printf("the number of characters is %d\n",n);
    return (n);
}// If you execute this as a separate program, you will get the number of characters in the string. Basically, you just have to modify this code to act as a separate function and when calling the function, you have to pass correct arguments.
```

//Use Pointers in the function to pass arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation was very thorough and helpful. The only part I am slightly confused is the "unsigned e = 5". So basically, you are using this e to track each letter of the two substrings to make sure they are different? And you are decreasing e by 1 each time, because if you increment it - it would hit the max character count of the substring, right?

Also, If I were to write a generalized code to fetch any substrings from the string, I would need to use pointers and malloc right?

Comment: Usage of 'e'- Assume APPLE and APPLICATION are in string. APPLICATION is substring you want to replace. Here first three letters are same. So, if I check only first letter, I might be confused and replace the APPLE. But I want APPLICATION to be replaced. Here, I would use 'e'=5(or anything, like 4,6) and check 1st letter and 5th letter.  If I increment, there is possibility that increment will happen above size of substring. So, I decrement and check whether 5th,4th,3rd,2nd,1st letter are matching. It's normally better if you choose 'e' as large as substring size. I dunno whether u got it?

Comment: Ya.You can use malloc. Also, u can write a separate function to get the number of characters in the string and return that function variable.For example-in the line: for(k=0;k<114;k++). Instead of using 114, you can use that variable. Similarly, you can do it for the substring. I didn't do it because, I didn't want to make the code complicated. If you still didn't understand 'e' part, let me know. I will try to explain more clearly. And I used 'unsigned int' because the 'e' wont go below 0 so that, the index 'e' will be in the range of size of substring. You can verify this by incrementing 'e'

Comment: Excellent! I completely understand why you used 'e = 5' and 'e--' now!

As for the other question. Let's say I have to make this code dynamic so that it can replace any substring within the string. Would I basically have to replace the variables within the first code?

Comment: I have edited the main answer. In the below(at the end, after explanation), I have mentioned a small piece of code. Just make that piece of code as a separate function and call that function to find the number of characters of whichever sub string you want. The returned variable 'n' can be used with proper arguments in place of, for example- 114 in the for loop, and in place of 10 in j<10 and j>=10. Also, you can use that 'n' variable and use it as unsigned int e=n-2. Try to figure out why I used n-2. Important point is, you have to pass the correct variables and call the function properly.

Comment: When I replace the 114 or 10 in the main function with n, it says that I am using an undeclared variable. So, does that mean that I need to declare 'n' in the main function as well? And should the function call be placed right before the printf in the main body - or at the very beginning of main?

Comment: Also, I edited my original code to show what I have so far.

Comment: You should create a new function and return the value of 'n'. Then assign a new variable and collect that passed data in main function. I edited the main code. You should place the function call before using the returned value in the main code. As you see I have used 3 function calls before 'for loop' and then used those returned values(r,r1,r2) inside the loop. And I have used last function call after the for loop and stored it in 'r3' because I will get the length of newstr only after executing the for loop.See the code and reply whether u understood? Just see step by step slowly and analyze

Comment: Thanks for commenting the code so clearly. I definitely have a better grasp on what's going on. One question: So now, are you saying that I have to add in the returned value in the main code, and then apply the function call before it?

Comment: I think you are not clear with the concepts of functions. I suggest you go through it once. Whenever you use the returned value in the main function, you will be calling it eventually. There are 3 parts in function. Function declaration(before main function), calling function(r,r1,r2), called function(after main function). You can change few variables and check the output. You will get more idea on what's going on.